# How to connect windows to Git bash for shell scripting and get output?

Tags: windows, git-bash

I connected my windows pc to Git Bash command prompt for shell scripting. But output not display in the GIT Bash Command prompt. What is the reason?

[image: Git Bash command prompt screenshot]

Comment: The contents of your _script_ is not actually bash, but Java. it must be compiled.

Comment: How can it compiled

Answer (score 0):

Since [`System.out.format()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-output-in-java/) is a Java command, you do not need a Git bash (useful to run shell script)

You only need to:

- [install Java](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-java-windows),
- install a [Java IDE](https://www.guru99.com/best-java-ide.html)
- rename your file as `script1.java`
- open that file in your IDE: you will have the options to compile it and run it then.

Comment: I want to develop a shell script which will show the total, and average of a given array of numbers. How to do it?

Comment: @ThiliniNIluka In pure bash, you can follow [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/calculate-column-average-using-bash-shell).